# Checked exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The case against checked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions)

EDIT: It appears I didn't phrase my question correctly, and I can understand the frustration.

I'm looking for some information that explains where I should use checked exceptions and where I should not use it. Most of the information on this subject is one sided - love/hate relationship. I think people make the assumption that one is bad over the other, or that developers always do a bad job about it.

EDIT 2: Ok, I did some Google searching (I wish I had done that before posting here), and found some balanced answers. I'm including them so it may help anyone looking for an answer, not another debate (like the duplicate post mentioned above)

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254.html

It appears Rod has a balanced discussion on this topic in his book, J2EE design without EJB:

http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=RodJohnsonInterview

It also appears that if you use validation on domain object, it would not be a bad idea to use checked exceptions. Anyway, if you read the materials above, you could be convinced about not using checked exceptions or minimize the chances of using it.

Rich, has provided an excellent link. Thanks, Rich!

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html

Some more:

http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/dev2arch/2006/11/effective-exceptions2.html

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2003/10/13.html

Comment: Please make your question less subjective and argumentative.

Comment: This is both a duplicate and subjective and argumentative.

Comment: This isn't a discussion website.  Do you actually want to be convinced that checked exceptions are bad?

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions

Comment: For a discussion on when to use checked vs unchecked exceptions, see http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html. Though the modern tendency is to avoid checked exceptions where possible

Comment: Rich, if the calling code should have a chance for handling the situation then a checked exception should be thrown.    This forces the programmer of the calling code to consider what should happen if the file is not found, if a network connection is broken, etc.

Comment: If the calling code should have a chance of handling the situation, I could code the calling code to ask for a boolean.

Comment: This does not seem like a duplicate. He's saying, given that I program in Java, which does have checked exceptions, where should I use them. That's different from, "why are checked exceptions a bad idea".

Comment: John, to be fair, when I posted this first, it sounded like a flame war. I subsequently reworded it, but it was too late and was voted for closure. I found some links, and I think I got the answer I was looking for. Thanks for stopping by :)

Answer (score -2):

Shaw, try having checked exceptions in code implementing an Iterator.

Case closed :-D

Comment: that would be very dumb thing to do. I would use hasNext().

Comment: The problem is that you _cannot_ throw checked exceptions through the Iterator interface as it doesn't declare any.    Hence, any exceptions happening there, must be unchecked.  See?

Comment: Most JDBC methods throw a checked exception, though that was not a good idea. The point is there could be cases where checked exceptions make sense.

Comment: The problem I tried to indicate was what to do if you inside the hasNext() call code which throws a checked exception and the code using the iterator should know about it.  You cannot do that directly as the hasNext() does not throw any checked exceptions.