# Defensive Programming: Guidelines in Java

Tags: java, exception, defensive-programming

I’m from a .NET background and now dabbling in Java.

Currently, I’m having big problems designing an API defensively against faulty input. Let’s say I’ve got the following code (close enough):

```
public void setTokens(Node node, int newTokens) {
    tokens.put(node, newTokens);
}
```

However, this code can fail for two reasons:

1. User passes a `null` node.
2. User passes an invalid node, i.e. one not contained in the graph.

In .NET, I would throw an [`ArgumentNullException`](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/07/11/180315.aspx) (rather than a `NullReferenceException`!) or an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28VS.80%29.aspx) respectively, passing the name of the offending argument (`node`) as a `string` argument.

Java doesn’t seem to have equivalent exceptions. I realize that I could be more specific and just throw whatever exception comes closest to describing the situation, or even writing my own exception class for the specific situation.

Is this the best practice? Or are there general-purpose classes similar to `ArgumentException` in .NET?

<del>Does it even make sense to check against `null` in this case? The code will fail anyway and the exception’s stack trace will contain the above method call. Checking against `null` seems redundant and excessive. Granted, the stack trace will be *slightly* cleaner (since its target is the above method, rather than an internal check in the `HashMap` implementation of the JRE). But this must be offset against the cost of an additional `if` statement, which, furthermore, should *never* occur anyway – after all, passing `null` to the above method isn’t an expected situation, it’s a rather stupid bug. Expecting it is downright paranoid – and it will fail with the same exception even if I don’t check for it.</del>

[As has been pointed out in the comments, `HashMap.put` actually allows `null` values for the key. So a check against `null` wouldn’t necessarily be redundant here.]

Comment: Calling `setTokens(null,0)` will only throw a `NullPointerException` if you are using `Hashtable` or `ConcurrentHashMap` as these don't allow `null` keys. `HashMap` on the other hand is happy to have null keys.

Comment: @pjp: Thanks for the correction – I had expected that to fail, since `HashMap` needs to create a hash of its argument. One more reason for explicit checking, I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Different groups have different standards.

Firstly, I assume you know the difference between `RuntimeException`s (unchecked) and normal `Exception`s (checked), if not then see [this question and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions). If you write your own exception you can force it to be caught, whereas both `NullPointerException` and `IllegalArgumentException` are RuntimeExceptions which are frowned on in some circles.

Secondly, as with you, groups I've worked with but don't actively use asserts, but if your team (or consumer of the API) has decided it will use asserts, then assert sounds like precisely the correct mechanism.

If I was you I would use `NullPointerException`. The reason for this is precedent. Take an example Java API from Sun, for example [java.util.TreeSet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Collection)). This uses NPEs for precisely this sort of situation, and while it does look like your code just used a null, it is entirely appropriate.

As others have said `IllegalArgumentException` is an option, but I think NullPointerException is more communicative.

If this API is designed to be used by outside companies/teams I would stick with `NullPointerException`, but make sure it is declared in the javadoc. If it is for internal use then you might decide that adding your own Exception heirarchy is worthwhile, but personally I find that APIs which add huge exception heirarchies, which are only going to be `printStackTrace()`d or logged are just a waste of effort.

At the end of the day the main thing is that your code communicates clearly. A local exception heirarchy is like local jargon - it adds information for insiders but can baffle outsiders.

As regards checking against null I would argue it does make sense. Firstly, it allows you to add a message about what was null (ie node or tokens) when you construct the exception which would be helpful. Secondly, in future you might use a `Map` implementation which allows `null`, and then you would lose the error check. The cost is almost nothing, so unless a profiler says it is an inner loop problem I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, that was really informative. As to checked vs. unchecked exceptions: violating the above invariants is a *bug* in the code, not a potentially viable condition. Using checked exceptions here would be quite insane – might as well make `NullPointerException` a checked exception, and put a `try` block around every single method call.

Comment: A descriptive _name_ for an exception might be very helpful when the stacktrace is the only clue you have to the problem.

Comment: @Thorbjørn I usually prefer good messages to better named exceptions, though clearly both are useful

Answer (score 12):

The standard Java exception is `IllegalArgumentException`. Some will throw `NullPointerException` if the argument is null, but for me NPE has that "someone screwed up" connotation, and you don't want clients of your API to think you don't know what you're doing.

For public APIs, check the arguments and fail early and cleanly. The time/cost barely matters.

Comment: +1 for the IAE vs NPE argument. I assume (rightly or wrongly) that an NPE is an unforseen fault, whereas an IAE (with an appropriate message) follows an explicit null check

Answer (score 7):

In Java you would normally throw an IllegalArgumentException

Comment: BTW. We use Jakarta Commons-Lang to do contract style checking.
E.g. Validate.notNull(node)
or
Validate.isTrue(node.isEmpty())

These throw IllegalArgumentExceptions for you

Comment: For some values of "normally".  I think that you will find a lot of the standard Java APIs throw NPE in preference to IAE when passed a null parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach depends entirely on what contract your function offers to callers - is it a precondition that node is not null?

If it is then you should throw an exception if node is null, since it is a contract violation. If it isnt then your function should silently handle the null Node and respond appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a guide about how to write good Java code, I can highly recommend the book [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/) by Joshua Bloch.

Comment: That book is already on my wish-list but I’m currently way over my budget for books. :-(

Comment: Best Java book ever. Possibly the best programming book ever.

Comment: Agree with Don. If you work a lot with Java, this book should have the absolute top priority over anything else on your wishlist. It deals with exactly the kind of things that you talk about in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this might be an appropriate use for an [assert](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html):

```
public void setTokens(Node node, int newTokens) {
    assert node != null;
    tokens.put(node, newTokens);
}
```

Comment: So does anybody actually compile with assertions enabled? I thought they were very much out of vogue and pretty much replaced by unit testing and other techniques.

Comment: Sure, I use asserts to check internal state. The important thing is that they can be enabled in the field. So if the program is behaving strangely, you have them run with asserts on, and it may tell you something useful about how the app is actually being used, which may not have been covered by a test.

But for public API, since you're going to test it explicitly anyway, an assert is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot depends on the contract of the method and how well the caller is known.

At some point in the process the caller could take action to validate the node before calling your method.  If you know the caller and know that these nodes are always validated then i think it is ok to assume you'll get good data. Essentially responsibility is on the caller.

However if you are, for example, providing a third party library that is distributed then you need to validate the node for nulls, etcs...

An illegalArugementException is the java standard but is also a RunTimeException.  So if you want to force the caller to handle the exception then you need to provided a check exception, probably a custom one you create.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd like NullPointerExceptions to ONLY happen by accident, so something else must be used to indicate that an illegal argument value was passed.  IllegalArgumentException is fine for this.

```
if (arg1 == null) {
 throw new IllegalArgumentException("arg1 == null");
}
```

This should be sufficient to both those reading the code, but also the poor soul who gets a support call at 3 in the morning.

(and, ALWAYS provide an explanatory text for your exceptions, you will appreciate them some sad day)

Answer (score 0):

like the other : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException.
About checking null Node, what about checking bad input at the Node creation ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have to please anybody, so what I do now as canonical code is

```
void method(String s) 

if((s != null) && (s instanceof String) && (s.length() > 0x0000))
{
```

which gets me a lot of sleep.

Others will disagree.

Comment: I'm not sure you need to do an instanceof check. The method signature requires something that is a String or a subclass of one, but the String is final.

Comment: @Platinum Azure: Compiler issue, should be checked at compile-time but I have seen it where one can get a class cast exception at runtime so I just put it in there. Seems to work better. There will be those who disagree. btw, I did some testing on string and it appears to make a copy of the char[] so char[0]++ has no effect ... any large shop with valuable property on the line will write their own compilers to avoid unkonwn on issues like this. Should be standard masers level cs.