# How do I use Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf() from Google Guava?

Tags: java, guava

[The javadoc example](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#propagateIfInstanceOf%28java.lang.Throwable%2C%20java.lang.Class%29)

```
  try {
    someMethodThatCouldThrowAnything();
  } catch (IKnowWhatToDoWithThisException e) {
    handle(e);
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(t, IOException.class);
    Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(t, SQLException.class);
    throw Throwables.propagate(t);
  }
```

is not very concrete. How would a real program look like? I don't really understand the purpose of the methods [`Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(Throwable, Class)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html#propagateIfInstanceOf%28java.lang.Throwable%2C%20java.lang.Class%29), `propagate()`, `propagateIfPossible()`. When do I use them?

Answer (score 17):

The purpose of these methods is to provide a convenient way to deal with checked exceptions.

`Throwables.propagate()` is a shorthand for the common idiom of retrowing checked exception wrapped into unchecked one (to avoid declaring it in method's `throws` clause).

`Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf()` is used to retrow checked exceptions as is if their types are declared in `throws` clause of the method.

In other words, the code in question

```
public void doSomething() 
    throws IOException, SQLException {

    try {
        someMethodThatCouldThrowAnything();
    } catch (IKnowWhatToDoWithThisException e) {
        handle(e);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(t, IOException.class);
        Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(t, SQLException.class);
        throw Throwables.propagate(t);
    }  
}
```

is a shorthand for the following code:

```
public void doSomething() 
    throws IOException, SQLException {

    try {
        someMethodThatCouldThrowAnything();
    } catch (IKnowWhatToDoWithThisException e) {
        handle(e);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException(t);
    }  
}
```

**See also:**

- [Checked versus unchecked exceptions](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129)
- [The case against checked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions)

Comment: The second version of the method you wrote isn't equivalent... you'd need to add two more `catch` blocks that just rethrow the exception... one for `RuntimeException` and one for `Error`. `Throwables.propagate` only wraps the throwable in a `RuntimeException` if it isn't already an unchecked exception.

Comment: I still don't unterstand. Why do I want to catch an exception if I want to propagate it anyway? I can do: public void doSomething()  throws IOException, SQLException { try { someMethodThatCouldThrowAnything(); } catch (IKnowWhatToDoWithThisException e) { handle(e); } }. This is not a real example ...

Comment: @Jeny: You can't do so is ` someMethodThatCouldThrowAnything()` can throw some checked exceptions other than `IOException` and `SQLException`.

Comment: True, then we wrap it in a RuntimeException and not re-thow as-is. That’s a different usecase and solely depends on Throwables.propagate(t) but it doesn’t explain a scenario without this behavior. Or do we always end blocks with propagate()? And is the whole idea ONLY to re-throw everything we can as-is and the rest in a RE and nothing else? Then I start to understand…

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the documentation of the Guava Throwables and I haven't found them really useful. Using throw new RuntimeException(e) is simpler to comprehend than Throwables.propagate(), in the scenario where you want to throw an unchecked exception wrapping a checked exception.

Comment: You don't have to check whatever your throwable is a specific checked exception, a runtime one or an error. It prevents for too many throwable encapsulation. It's not unusual to see kilometers of wrapped RuntimeException which leads to a very long stack traces to go through. And finally see that the only last has value.

Answer (score 0):

One scenario I can provide for anyone who'll find this useful is if you have a method wrapping any exceptions thrown, then this can be used to unwrap/cast the cause into specific exception.

Example: the [get](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html#get%28K%29) method in Guava's LoadingCache wraps all checked exceptions into [ExecutionException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html?is-external=true). The documentation states that the exception can be inspected using [getCause()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29).

Here `Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf` can be used to throw specific exceptions for the calling method to handle, if we know that `cache.get()` will throw those exceptions (maybe specific to LoadingCache, but if value is misisng, the cache tries to load a value which can throw checked exceptions).

```
public String getCacheValue(String key) throws SQLException{
  try{
       return cache.get(key);
  }catch(ExecutedException ex){
       Throwables.propagateIfInstanceOf(ex.getCause(), SQLException.class);
       Throwables.propagate(ex);
  }
}
```