# How to catch NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java

For starters, I'm aware that this question involves bad coding practice, but my teacher has required it.

Okay, so I'm using .next() of the scanner class and my teacher has specified that I must catch and handle the NoSuchElementException.  My code will not compile and I am receiving this error

School.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
               catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                      ^
  symbol:   class NoSuchElementException
  location: class School

Do I have to import something to catch a NoSuchElementException?

Here's the code in question.

```
while (file.hasNext()) {
     record = file.nextLine();
     Scanner info = new Scanner(record).useDelimiter(";");
     type = Character.toUpperCase(info.next().trim().charAt(0));

     switch(type) {
        case 'U':
           try {
              idNumber = info.next().trim();
              name = info.next().trim();
              credits = Integer.parseInt(info.next().trim());
              residency = Integer.parseInt(info.next().trim());
              Undergraduate u = new Undergraduate(idNumber, name, credits,
                 residency);
              addStudent(u);
           }
           catch (NegativeValueException e) {
              addExcludedRecord(e + " occurred while processing:\n" + record);
           }
           catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              addExcludedRecord(e + " occurred while processing:\n" + record);
           }
           catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
              addExcludedRecord(e + " occurred while processing:\n" + record);
           }
           break;
```

This is just the first case of the switch because I didn't want to include everything.  Here is a sample of a line of the file that is being read by the Scanner.

Ugrad; 1234567890; Jones, Sam; 16; 1

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: I just added that.  Sorry I didn't copy correctly the first time.

Comment: I mean ... you have to import the exception; it's a class just like anything else.

Comment: Import it. What's the bad practice part?

Comment: @DaveNewton catching an unchecked exception, probably

Comment: Have you imported it? (`java.util.NoSuchElementException`)

Comment: From everything I've read you shouldn't catch a NoSuchElementException because it is a runtime exception and instead you should use hasNext().

Comment: You can lookup in which package a class is in the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Comment: I didn't import it.  That fixed the problem.  Why do you have to import NoSuchElement but not NumberFormatException?  NegativeValueException is a custom exception that I wrote so I understand why that doesn't need to be imported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to catch a NoSuchElementException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5672134/how-to-catch-a-nosuchelementexception)

Comment: I read that question already and it didn't answer what I was asking.

Comment: fge thanks for the answer, that solved the problem.  If you want to write an answer I'll select it.

Comment: Catching an unchecked exception isn't intrinsically at bad

Comment: To answer your follow-up question: the fully qualified name of `NumberFormatException` is `java.lang.NumberFormatException` and to save typing, everything in the `java.lang` package is imported by default. Everything else you need to import unless it's in the same package as the code that uses it (as is the case with your custom `NegativeValueException`).

Comment: @Dave You should try to call the method instead of catching the exception when possible.  There is a slight performance penalty for catching exceptions because an exception object has to be instantiated.

Comment: @Michael Exceptions already indicate an exceptional circumstance, so the performance penalty is assumed. My point is that catching an RTE isn't intrinsically bad if that's the API's behavior. If there are other solutions, they should be tested for performance, *if* it's determined it's *actually* an issue in overall application performance. Which I find unlikely in this case.

Comment: No need for that; and @biziclop explained the problem here: all of `java.lang` is automatically imported and `NumberFormatException` is in `java.lang`.

Comment: @Dave Agreed.  I was just thinking of examples like `NoSuchElementException` (you should call `hasNext()` instead) and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (you should always check an array's bounds yourself).