# Java Malformed URL Exception

Tags: java, android, malformedurlexception

I'm trying to make an http POST request in an android app I'm building, but no matter what url I use for the request, Eclipse keeps raising a Malformed URL Exception. I've tried a line of code from one of the android tutorials:

```
URL url = new URL("https://wikipedia.org");
```

And even that triggers the error. Is there a reason Eclipse keeps raising this error for any URL I try to create?

Comment: Post your code and LogCat.

Comment: Works fine for me. Post the stack trace.

Comment: And please put the code in your question, and not in comments.

Comment: Do you mean that the exception is actually being thrown? Or you simply mean Eclipse keeps telling you about the Exception? If it's the latter, it's because MalformedURLException is a [checked exception](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=what+is+a+checked+exception&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb&gfe_rd=cr&ei=JyerU7K8IojY8geYjICwDw), i.e., you must explicitly deal with it in code, either by wrapping it in a try/catch statement, or by adding `throws MalformedURLException` to the method stub.

Comment: is this line inside a try-catch block?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It is not raising the exception, it's complaining that you haven't handled [**the possibility that it might**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html), even though it won't, because the URL in this case is not malformed. (Java's designers thought this concept, "checked exceptions", was a good idea, although in practice [it hasn't worked well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions))

To shut it up, add `throws MalformedURLException`, or its superclass `throws IOException`, to the method declaration. For example:

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://wikipedia.org/");
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, catch and rethrow the annoying exception as an unchecked exception:

```
public void myMethod() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://wikipedia.org/");
        ...
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Java 8 added the `UncheckedIOException` class for rethrowing `IOException`s when you cannot otherwise handle them. In earlier Java versions, use `RuntimeException`.

Comment: Checked exceptions are not a bad idea. How they are being used in the case of `MalformedURLException` is. `MalformedURLException` should not be a checked exception, but the Java team made it so for some reason I am yet to understand.

Comment: **unhandled exception** means the exception needs to be **handled**

Comment: was using the new url in asynch doInBackground... only way i could get around the error. Thanks !