# malformedURLException when declaring URL with string in Android

Tags: android

According to Android reference you can declare an URL using a string.

That means that the next code is supposed to be correct(i.e):

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
```

When I try to use it I get:

> "java.net.MalformedURLException"

It happens to me on AndroidStudio 1.2.1.1

The full code I'm trying to use comes from the references of HttpURLConnect of Android:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
   HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
   try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
    finally {
     urlConnection.disconnect();
   }
 }
```

Comment: It's good, can you show me the complete code?, and what do you see when logging the getMessage() of the error?

Comment: Sure, i have edited the main post.

Comment: Have you wrapped the code block with try-catch block which catch the MalFormedUrlException ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

[Java Malformed URL Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416930/java-malformed-url-exception)

The answer says: 
It is not raising the error, it's complaining that you haven't handled the possibility that it might, even though it won't, because the URL in this case is not malformed. Java seems to think this is a good idea. (It's not.)

To shut it up, add throws MalformedURLException or throws IOException to the method declaration. E.g.:

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://wikipedia.org/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works perfectly fine here

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    urlConnection.disconnect();

} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```