# exception IOException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java

I am not too stupid to realize that the code in the 'try catch' cannot throw an exception. But I am stuck here because I have copied the code exactly from the book so it must have been correct when published. It's left me wondering if the code can't compile anymore because it's out of date? I realize the nature of this question may offend some people here. If so please just don't be TOO harsh in your stern reprimands.

I am getting the error :

> ./StreamCopier.java:13: error: exception IOException is never thrown in body of      corresponding try statement
>                   } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}

```
//FileTyper.java
//Reads filenames from the command line and copies named files onto System.out.

import java.io.*;

public class FileTyper  {

  public static void main (String[] args)  {

    if (args.length == 0)  {
      System.err.print("usage: java FileTyper file1, file2");
      return;
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < args.length ; i++)  {
      try  {
        typeFile(args[i]);
        if (i+1 < args.length)  {    //more files waiting to be processed
          System.out.println();
          System.out.println("********************************************");
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}
    } //end for

  } //end main()

  public static void typeFile (String filename) throws IOException  {

    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
    StreamCopier.copy(fin, System.out);
    fin.close();
  }
}


//StreamCopier.java
//hard to know what this program does exactly

import java.io.*;

public class StreamCopier  {

  public static void main (String[] args)  {

    try  {

    } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);}

  }

  public static void copy (InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException  {

    //do not allow other threads to read from the  input or
    //write to the output while copying is taking place.
    synchronized (in)  {
      synchronized (out)  {
        byte [] buffer = new byte [256];
        while (true) {
          int bytesRead = in.read(buffer);
          if (bytesRead == -1) break;
          out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
      }
    }

  }  //end copy()

}
```

Comment: The error message from the compiler is for StreamCopier.java. The code you posted is FileTyper.java. BTW, this try block can throw an IOException, since it calls typeFile(), which throws IOException.

Comment: Gotchya : Heres the StreamCopier class :

Comment: You have an empty try block and asking yourself why this error appears?

Comment: The try block is empty in the text book too however. You can see it on page 49 of this .pdf here : http://www.dblab.ntua.gr/~gtsat/collection/Java%20books/O%27Reilly%20-%20Java%20IO.pdf

Comment: @user3814983 This sample more looks like a template. His main class is empty therefore his program won't do anything if he executes it.

Comment: True true. The empty try catch seemed wrong to me when I first read it but I failed to see that programs further on in the book were relying on that code. Thanks alot for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the empty try {} catch {} block in the main method of StreamCopier.java. Remove the empty try{} catch{} block and then try. It should work.

```
public static void main (String[] args)  {
            try  {


            } catch (IOException e) {System.err.println(e);} // here is the problem
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `try` block is empty, apparently because you haven't written the code that goes in it yet. The Java compiler stupidly complains if there is a `catch` block and [it thinks] the exception cannot be thrown. This is one of the annoying qualities of Java's [checked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions).

Simply continue to fill in the `try` block, and the error will go away. You can insert a dummy `copy(null, null);` inside it to make the compiler shut up.

Comment: Thanks. Putting in copy(null, null); sorted the problem. I dont think i've ever had a question fixed so fast :D

Comment: There nothing 'stupid' about it. In th case it has alerted the OP to an error that would have been even harder to track down without it.

Comment: @EJP It is stupid. All it does it complicate debugging and editing. The compiler can't actually figure out where checked exceptions are thrown from anyway, because there are ways to throw checked exceptions without telling it, so then it prevents you from catching legitimate exceptions. It also prevents improving methods to throw less exceptions because it would break existing catch blocks.