# How to handle errors with boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I am trying to figure how to do proper error handling with boto3.

I am trying to create an IAM user:

```
def create_user(username, iam_conn):
    try:
        user = iam_conn.create_user(UserName=username)
        return user
    except Exception as e:
        return e
```

When the call to create_user succeeds, I get a neat object that contains the http status code of the API call and the data of the newly created user.

Example:

```
{'ResponseMetadata': 
      {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 
       'RequestId': 'omitted'
      },
 u'User': {u'Arn': 'arn:aws:iam::omitted:user/omitted',
           u'CreateDate': datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 11, 17, 13, 5, 882000, tzinfo=tzutc()),
           u'Path': '/',
           u'UserId': 'omitted',
           u'UserName': 'omitted'
          }
}
```

This works great. But when this fails (like if the user already exists), I just get an object of type botocore.exceptions.ClientError with only text to tell me what went wrong.

Example:
ClientError('An error occurred (EntityAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateUser operation: User with name omitted already exists.',)

This (AFAIK) makes error handling very hard because I can't just switch on the resulting http status code (409 for user already exists according to the AWS API docs for IAM). This makes me think that I must be doing something the wrong way. The optimal way would be for boto3 to never throw exceptions, but juts always return an object that reflects how the API call went.

Can anyone enlighten me on this issue or point me in the right direction?

Comment: AWS docs http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client_upgrades.html#error-handling

Answer (score 620, accepted):

Use the response contained within the exception. Here is an example:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

try:
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    user = iam.create_user(UserName='fred')
    print("Created user: %s" % user)
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'EntityAlreadyExists':
        print("User already exists")
    else:
        print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```

The response dict in the exception will contain the following:

- `['Error']['Code']` e.g. 'EntityAlreadyExists' or 'ValidationError'
- `['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']` e.g. 400
- `['ResponseMetadata']['RequestId']` e.g. 'd2b06652-88d7-11e5-99d0-812348583a35'
- `['Error']['Message']` e.g. "An error occurred (EntityAlreadyExists) ..."
- `['Error']['Type']` e.g. 'Sender'

For more information see:

- [boto3 error handling](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html)
- [botocore error handling](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client_upgrades.html#error-handling)

**[Updated: 2018-03-07]**

The AWS Python SDK has begun to expose service exceptions on [clients](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html) (though not on [resources](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migration.html#resource-objects)) that you can explicitly catch, so it is now possible to write that code like this:

```
import botocore
import boto3

try:
    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    user = iam.create_user(UserName='fred')
    print("Created user: %s" % user)
except iam.exceptions.EntityAlreadyExistsException:
    print("User already exists")
except botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError as e:
    print("Parameter validation error: %s" % e)
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    print("Unexpected error: %s" % e)
```

Unfortunately, there is currently no documentation for these errors/exceptions but you can get a list of the core errors as follows:

```
import botocore
import boto3
[e for e in dir(botocore.exceptions) if e.endswith('Error')]
```

Note that you must import both botocore and boto3. If you only import botocore then you will find that botocore has no attribute named `exceptions`. This is because the exceptions are dynamically populated into botocore by boto3.

You can get a list of service-specific exceptions as follows (replace `iam` with the relevant service as needed):

```
import boto3
iam = boto3.client('iam')
[e for e in dir(iam.exceptions) if e.endswith('Exception')]
```

**[Updated: 2021-09-07]**

In addition to the aforementioned client exception method, there is also a third-party helper package named [aws-error-utils](https://github.com/benkehoe/aws-error-utils).

Comment: while using client should we check HTTPStatusCode in response  resp["ResponseMetadata"].get("HTTPStatusCode") != 200? I mean does the api always throw exception if status code is not 200?

Comment: @himanshu219 Good question.There's no clear guidance on this and a search for HTTPStatusCode in the boto3 docs yields no results. In my experience, however, you can rely on an exception being thrown.

Comment: In any event, you should not use **only** `200` in your check, as the return code could be a different `2xx` HTTP status code (e.g., `204` when deleting a vault or archive, `201` when creating, etc.). 

At best, one should check for a non-4xx code (e.g., `statusCode < 400`) but that's really brittle and I would not recommend it anyway: best to rely on `boto` throwing exceptions at your code.

Comment: Yes, the api always throws exceptions. See https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/client_upgrades.html#error-handling

Comment: I really miss checked exceptions.

Comment: @JeffHeaton interesting read on that very topic at [the case against checked exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions). My take is that the lack of an explicit (or at least documented) interface/contract with a function is a real impediment.

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading this in 2021 that sometimes the error code for an entity that already exists is 'ResourceAlreadyExistsException' instead of 'EntityAlreadyExists'

Comment: @DanielKats hopefully once [AWS Cloud Control API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-cloud-control-api/) becomes ubiquitous, the error will be consistent (AlreadyExistsException).

Comment: Just watch out for HEAD operations, e.g. checking to see if an S3 bucket exists with `head_bucket`. The docs say it will raise a `NoSuchBucket` error but it actually raises a `ClientError`. See https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1262#issuecomment-1011266230.

Answer (score 36):

I found it very useful, since the Exceptions are not documented, to list all exceptions to the screen for this package. Here is the code I used to do it:

```
import botocore.exceptions
def listexns(mod):
    #module = __import__(mod)
    exns = []
    for name in botocore.exceptions.__dict__:
        if (isinstance(botocore.exceptions.__dict__[name], Exception) or
            name.endswith('Error')):
            exns.append(name)
    for name in exns:
        print('%s.%s is an exception type' % (str(mod), name))
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print('Give me a module name on the $PYTHONPATH!')
    print('Looking for exception types in module: %s' % sys.argv[1])
    listexns(sys.argv[1])
```

Which results in:

```
Looking for exception types in module: boto3
boto3.BotoCoreError is an exception type
boto3.DataNotFoundError is an exception type
boto3.UnknownServiceError is an exception type
boto3.ApiVersionNotFoundError is an exception type
boto3.HTTPClientError is an exception type
boto3.ConnectionError is an exception type
boto3.EndpointConnectionError is an exception type
boto3.SSLError is an exception type
boto3.ConnectionClosedError is an exception type
boto3.ReadTimeoutError is an exception type
boto3.ConnectTimeoutError is an exception type
boto3.ProxyConnectionError is an exception type
boto3.NoCredentialsError is an exception type
boto3.PartialCredentialsError is an exception type
boto3.CredentialRetrievalError is an exception type
boto3.UnknownSignatureVersionError is an exception type
boto3.ServiceNotInRegionError is an exception type
boto3.BaseEndpointResolverError is an exception type
boto3.NoRegionError is an exception type
boto3.UnknownEndpointError is an exception type
boto3.ConfigParseError is an exception type
boto3.MissingParametersError is an exception type
boto3.ValidationError is an exception type
boto3.ParamValidationError is an exception type
boto3.UnknownKeyError is an exception type
boto3.RangeError is an exception type
boto3.UnknownParameterError is an exception type
boto3.AliasConflictParameterError is an exception type
boto3.PaginationError is an exception type
boto3.OperationNotPageableError is an exception type
boto3.ChecksumError is an exception type
boto3.UnseekableStreamError is an exception type
boto3.WaiterError is an exception type
boto3.IncompleteReadError is an exception type
boto3.InvalidExpressionError is an exception type
boto3.UnknownCredentialError is an exception type
boto3.WaiterConfigError is an exception type
boto3.UnknownClientMethodError is an exception type
boto3.UnsupportedSignatureVersionError is an exception type
boto3.ClientError is an exception type
boto3.EventStreamError is an exception type
boto3.InvalidDNSNameError is an exception type
boto3.InvalidS3AddressingStyleError is an exception type
boto3.InvalidRetryConfigurationError is an exception type
boto3.InvalidMaxRetryAttemptsError is an exception type
boto3.StubResponseError is an exception type
boto3.StubAssertionError is an exception type
boto3.UnStubbedResponseError is an exception type
boto3.InvalidConfigError is an exception type
boto3.InfiniteLoopConfigError is an exception type
boto3.RefreshWithMFAUnsupportedError is an exception type
boto3.MD5UnavailableError is an exception type
boto3.MetadataRetrievalError is an exception type
boto3.UndefinedModelAttributeError is an exception type
boto3.MissingServiceIdError is an exception type
```

Comment: Is there a Base Class for botocore exceptions, the way Python has "Exception"?

Comment: Yes, the base class is `Boto3Error`.

Comment: Additionally, you can also get a list of client based exceptions by running the python interpreter by running something like this: `import boto3` `s3_client=boto3.client('s3')` `s3_client.exceptions.blah`. blah is not an attribute, so it will error and list all the valid exceptions.

Answer (score 27):

Just an update to the 'no exceptions on resources' problem as pointed to by @jarmod (do please feel free to update your answer if below seems applicable)

I have tested the below code and it runs fine. It uses 'resources' for *doing* things, but catches the `client.exceptions` - although it 'looks' somewhat wrong... it tests good, the exception classes are showing and matching when looked into using debugger at exception time...

It may not be applicable to all resources and clients, but works for data folders (aka s3 buckets).

```
lab_session = boto3.Session() 
c = lab_session.client('s3') #this client is only for exception catching

try:
    b = s3.Bucket(bucket)
    b.delete()
except c.exceptions.NoSuchBucket as e:
    #ignoring no such bucket exceptions
    logger.debug("Failed deleting bucket. Continuing. {}".format(e))
except Exception as e:
    #logging all the others as warning
    logger.warning("Failed deleting bucket. Continuing. {}".format(e))
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: FYI: this can be accomplished without predefining a client using: `s3.meta.client.exceptions.NoSuchBucket`

Comment: what is s3 here?

Comment: `s3` is the service resource, e.g. `s3 = boto3.resource('s3')`. Works also for the actual resources, such as buckets: `boto3.resource('s3').Bucket('bucket-name').meta.client.exceptions. ...`

Answer (score 27):

As a few others already mentioned, you can catch certain errors using the service client (`service_client.exceptions.<ExceptionClass>`) or resource (`service_resource.meta.client.exceptions.<ExceptionClass>`), however it is not well documented (also which exceptions belong to which clients). So here is how to get the complete mapping at time of writing (January 2020) in region EU (Ireland) (`eu-west-1`):

```py
import boto3, pprint

region_name = 'eu-west-1'
session = boto3.Session(region_name=region_name)
exceptions = {
  service: list(boto3.client(service).exceptions._code_to_exception)
  for service in session.get_available_services()
}
pprint.pprint(exceptions, width=20000)
```

Here is a subset of the pretty large document:

```
{'acm': ['InvalidArnException', 'InvalidDomainValidationOptionsException', 'InvalidStateException', 'InvalidTagException', 'LimitExceededException', 'RequestInProgressException', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'TooManyTagsException'],
 'apigateway': ['BadRequestException', 'ConflictException', 'LimitExceededException', 'NotFoundException', 'ServiceUnavailableException', 'TooManyRequestsException', 'UnauthorizedException'],
 'athena': ['InternalServerException', 'InvalidRequestException', 'TooManyRequestsException'],
 'autoscaling': ['AlreadyExists', 'InvalidNextToken', 'LimitExceeded', 'ResourceContention', 'ResourceInUse', 'ScalingActivityInProgress', 'ServiceLinkedRoleFailure'],
 'cloudformation': ['AlreadyExistsException', 'ChangeSetNotFound', 'CreatedButModifiedException', 'InsufficientCapabilitiesException', 'InvalidChangeSetStatus', 'InvalidOperationException', 'LimitExceededException', 'NameAlreadyExistsException', 'OperationIdAlreadyExistsException', 'OperationInProgressException', 'OperationNotFoundException', 'StackInstanceNotFoundException', 'StackSetNotEmptyException', 'StackSetNotFoundException', 'StaleRequestException', 'TokenAlreadyExistsException'],
 'cloudfront': ['AccessDenied', 'BatchTooLarge', 'CNAMEAlreadyExists', 'CannotChangeImmutablePublicKeyFields', 'CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityAlreadyExists', 'CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityInUse', 'DistributionAlreadyExists', 'DistributionNotDisabled', 'FieldLevelEncryptionConfigAlreadyExists', 'FieldLevelEncryptionConfigInUse', 'FieldLevelEncryptionProfileAlreadyExists', 'FieldLevelEncryptionProfileInUse', 'FieldLevelEncryptionProfileSizeExceeded', 'IllegalFieldLevelEncryptionConfigAssociationWithCacheBehavior', 'IllegalUpdate', 'InconsistentQuantities', 'InvalidArgument', 'InvalidDefaultRootObject', 'InvalidErrorCode', 'InvalidForwardCookies', 'InvalidGeoRestrictionParameter', 'InvalidHeadersForS3Origin', 'InvalidIfMatchVersion', 'InvalidLambdaFunctionAssociation', 'InvalidLocationCode', 'InvalidMinimumProtocolVersion', 'InvalidOrigin', 'InvalidOriginAccessIdentity', 'InvalidOriginKeepaliveTimeout', 'InvalidOriginReadTimeout', 'InvalidProtocolSettings', 'InvalidQueryStringParameters', 'InvalidRelativePath', 'InvalidRequiredProtocol', 'InvalidResponseCode', 'InvalidTTLOrder', 'InvalidTagging', 'InvalidViewerCertificate', 'InvalidWebACLId', 'MissingBody', 'NoSuchCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity', 'NoSuchDistribution', 'NoSuchFieldLevelEncryptionConfig', 'NoSuchFieldLevelEncryptionProfile', 'NoSuchInvalidation', 'NoSuchOrigin', 'NoSuchPublicKey', 'NoSuchResource', 'NoSuchStreamingDistribution', 'PreconditionFailed', 'PublicKeyAlreadyExists', 'PublicKeyInUse', 'QueryArgProfileEmpty', 'StreamingDistributionAlreadyExists', 'StreamingDistributionNotDisabled', 'TooManyCacheBehaviors', 'TooManyCertificates', 'TooManyCloudFrontOriginAccessIdentities', 'TooManyCookieNamesInWhiteList', 'TooManyDistributionCNAMEs', 'TooManyDistributions', 'TooManyDistributionsAssociatedToFieldLevelEncryptionConfig', 'TooManyDistributionsWithLambdaAssociations', 'TooManyFieldLevelEncryptionConfigs', 'TooManyFieldLevelEncryptionContentTypeProfiles', 'TooManyFieldLevelEncryptionEncryptionEntities', 'TooManyFieldLevelEncryptionFieldPatterns', 'TooManyFieldLevelEncryptionProfiles', 'TooManyFieldLevelEncryptionQueryArgProfiles', 'TooManyHeadersInForwardedValues', 'TooManyInvalidationsInProgress', 'TooManyLambdaFunctionAssociations', 'TooManyOriginCustomHeaders', 'TooManyOriginGroupsPerDistribution', 'TooManyOrigins', 'TooManyPublicKeys', 'TooManyQueryStringParameters', 'TooManyStreamingDistributionCNAMEs', 'TooManyStreamingDistributions', 'TooManyTrustedSigners', 'TrustedSignerDoesNotExist'],
 'cloudtrail': ['CloudTrailARNInvalidException', 'CloudTrailAccessNotEnabledException', 'CloudWatchLogsDeliveryUnavailableException', 'InsufficientDependencyServiceAccessPermissionException', 'InsufficientEncryptionPolicyException', 'InsufficientS3BucketPolicyException', 'InsufficientSnsTopicPolicyException', 'InvalidCloudWatchLogsLogGroupArnException', 'InvalidCloudWatchLogsRoleArnException', 'InvalidEventSelectorsException', 'InvalidHomeRegionException', 'InvalidKmsKeyIdException', 'InvalidLookupAttributesException', 'InvalidMaxResultsException', 'InvalidNextTokenException', 'InvalidParameterCombinationException', 'InvalidS3BucketNameException', 'InvalidS3PrefixException', 'InvalidSnsTopicNameException', 'InvalidTagParameterException', 'InvalidTimeRangeException', 'InvalidTokenException', 'InvalidTrailNameException', 'KmsException', 'KmsKeyDisabledException', 'KmsKeyNotFoundException', 'MaximumNumberOfTrailsExceededException', 'NotOrganizationMasterAccountException', 'OperationNotPermittedException', 'OrganizationNotInAllFeaturesModeException', 'OrganizationsNotInUseException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ResourceTypeNotSupportedException', 'S3BucketDoesNotExistException', 'TagsLimitExceededException', 'TrailAlreadyExistsException', 'TrailNotFoundException', 'TrailNotProvidedException', 'UnsupportedOperationException'],
 'cloudwatch': ['InvalidParameterInput', 'ResourceNotFound', 'InternalServiceError', 'InvalidFormat', 'InvalidNextToken', 'InvalidParameterCombination', 'InvalidParameterValue', 'LimitExceeded', 'MissingParameter'],
 'codebuild': ['AccountLimitExceededException', 'InvalidInputException', 'OAuthProviderException', 'ResourceAlreadyExistsException', 'ResourceNotFoundException'],
 'config': ['InsufficientDeliveryPolicyException', 'InsufficientPermissionsException', 'InvalidConfigurationRecorderNameException', 'InvalidDeliveryChannelNameException', 'InvalidLimitException', 'InvalidNextTokenException', 'InvalidParameterValueException', 'InvalidRecordingGroupException', 'InvalidResultTokenException', 'InvalidRoleException', 'InvalidS3KeyPrefixException', 'InvalidSNSTopicARNException', 'InvalidTimeRangeException', 'LastDeliveryChannelDeleteFailedException', 'LimitExceededException', 'MaxNumberOfConfigRulesExceededException', 'MaxNumberOfConfigurationRecordersExceededException', 'MaxNumberOfDeliveryChannelsExceededException', 'MaxNumberOfRetentionConfigurationsExceededException', 'NoAvailableConfigurationRecorderException', 'NoAvailableDeliveryChannelException', 'NoAvailableOrganizationException', 'NoRunningConfigurationRecorderException', 'NoSuchBucketException', 'NoSuchConfigRuleException', 'NoSuchConfigurationAggregatorException', 'NoSuchConfigurationRecorderException', 'NoSuchDeliveryChannelException', 'NoSuchRetentionConfigurationException', 'OrganizationAccessDeniedException', 'OrganizationAllFeaturesNotEnabledException', 'OversizedConfigurationItemException', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceNotDiscoveredException', 'ValidationException'],
 'dynamodb': ['BackupInUseException', 'BackupNotFoundException', 'ConditionalCheckFailedException', 'ContinuousBackupsUnavailableException', 'GlobalTableAlreadyExistsException', 'GlobalTableNotFoundException', 'IdempotentParameterMismatchException', 'IndexNotFoundException', 'InternalServerError', 'InvalidRestoreTimeException', 'ItemCollectionSizeLimitExceededException', 'LimitExceededException', 'PointInTimeRecoveryUnavailableException', 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException', 'ReplicaAlreadyExistsException', 'ReplicaNotFoundException', 'RequestLimitExceeded', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'TableAlreadyExistsException', 'TableInUseException', 'TableNotFoundException', 'TransactionCanceledException', 'TransactionConflictException', 'TransactionInProgressException'],
 'ec2': [],
 'ecr': ['EmptyUploadException', 'ImageAlreadyExistsException', 'ImageNotFoundException', 'InvalidLayerException', 'InvalidLayerPartException', 'InvalidParameterException', 'InvalidTagParameterException', 'LayerAlreadyExistsException', 'LayerInaccessibleException', 'LayerPartTooSmallException', 'LayersNotFoundException', 'LifecyclePolicyNotFoundException', 'LifecyclePolicyPreviewInProgressException', 'LifecyclePolicyPreviewNotFoundException', 'LimitExceededException', 'RepositoryAlreadyExistsException', 'RepositoryNotEmptyException', 'RepositoryNotFoundException', 'RepositoryPolicyNotFoundException', 'ServerException', 'TooManyTagsException', 'UploadNotFoundException'],
 'ecs': ['AccessDeniedException', 'AttributeLimitExceededException', 'BlockedException', 'ClientException', 'ClusterContainsContainerInstancesException', 'ClusterContainsServicesException', 'ClusterContainsTasksException', 'ClusterNotFoundException', 'InvalidParameterException', 'MissingVersionException', 'NoUpdateAvailableException', 'PlatformTaskDefinitionIncompatibilityException', 'PlatformUnknownException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ServerException', 'ServiceNotActiveException', 'ServiceNotFoundException', 'TargetNotFoundException', 'UnsupportedFeatureException', 'UpdateInProgressException'],
 'efs': ['BadRequest', 'DependencyTimeout', 'FileSystemAlreadyExists', 'FileSystemInUse', 'FileSystemLimitExceeded', 'FileSystemNotFound', 'IncorrectFileSystemLifeCycleState', 'IncorrectMountTargetState', 'InsufficientThroughputCapacity', 'InternalServerError', 'IpAddressInUse', 'MountTargetConflict', 'MountTargetNotFound', 'NetworkInterfaceLimitExceeded', 'NoFreeAddressesInSubnet', 'SecurityGroupLimitExceeded', 'SecurityGroupNotFound', 'SubnetNotFound', 'ThroughputLimitExceeded', 'TooManyRequests', 'UnsupportedAvailabilityZone'],
 'eks': ['ClientException', 'InvalidParameterException', 'InvalidRequestException', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceLimitExceededException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ServerException', 'ServiceUnavailableException', 'UnsupportedAvailabilityZoneException'],
 'elasticache': ['APICallRateForCustomerExceeded', 'AuthorizationAlreadyExists', 'AuthorizationNotFound', 'CacheClusterAlreadyExists', 'CacheClusterNotFound', 'CacheParameterGroupAlreadyExists', 'CacheParameterGroupNotFound', 'CacheParameterGroupQuotaExceeded', 'CacheSecurityGroupAlreadyExists', 'CacheSecurityGroupNotFound', 'QuotaExceeded.CacheSecurityGroup', 'CacheSubnetGroupAlreadyExists', 'CacheSubnetGroupInUse', 'CacheSubnetGroupNotFoundFault', 'CacheSubnetGroupQuotaExceeded', 'CacheSubnetQuotaExceededFault', 'ClusterQuotaForCustomerExceeded', 'InsufficientCacheClusterCapacity', 'InvalidARN', 'InvalidCacheClusterState', 'InvalidCacheParameterGroupState', 'InvalidCacheSecurityGroupState', 'InvalidParameterCombination', 'InvalidParameterValue', 'InvalidReplicationGroupState', 'InvalidSnapshotState', 'InvalidSubnet', 'InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault', 'NoOperationFault', 'NodeGroupNotFoundFault', 'NodeGroupsPerReplicationGroupQuotaExceeded', 'NodeQuotaForClusterExceeded', 'NodeQuotaForCustomerExceeded', 'ReplicationGroupAlreadyExists', 'ReplicationGroupNotFoundFault', 'ReservedCacheNodeAlreadyExists', 'ReservedCacheNodeNotFound', 'ReservedCacheNodeQuotaExceeded', 'ReservedCacheNodesOfferingNotFound', 'ServiceLinkedRoleNotFoundFault', 'SnapshotAlreadyExistsFault', 'SnapshotFeatureNotSupportedFault', 'SnapshotNotFoundFault', 'SnapshotQuotaExceededFault', 'SubnetInUse', 'TagNotFound', 'TagQuotaPerResourceExceeded', 'TestFailoverNotAvailableFault'],
 'elasticbeanstalk': ['CodeBuildNotInServiceRegionException', 'ElasticBeanstalkServiceException', 'InsufficientPrivilegesException', 'InvalidRequestException', 'ManagedActionInvalidStateException', 'OperationInProgressFailure', 'PlatformVersionStillReferencedException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ResourceTypeNotSupportedException', 'S3LocationNotInServiceRegionException', 'S3SubscriptionRequiredException', 'SourceBundleDeletionFailure', 'TooManyApplicationVersionsException', 'TooManyApplicationsException', 'TooManyBucketsException', 'TooManyConfigurationTemplatesException', 'TooManyEnvironmentsException', 'TooManyPlatformsException', 'TooManyTagsException'],
 'elb': ['LoadBalancerNotFound', 'CertificateNotFound', 'DependencyThrottle', 'DuplicateLoadBalancerName', 'DuplicateListener', 'DuplicatePolicyName', 'DuplicateTagKeys', 'InvalidConfigurationRequest', 'InvalidInstance', 'InvalidScheme', 'InvalidSecurityGroup', 'InvalidSubnet', 'ListenerNotFound', 'LoadBalancerAttributeNotFound', 'OperationNotPermitted', 'PolicyNotFound', 'PolicyTypeNotFound', 'SubnetNotFound', 'TooManyLoadBalancers', 'TooManyPolicies', 'TooManyTags', 'UnsupportedProtocol'],
 'emr': ['InternalServerError', 'InternalServerException', 'InvalidRequestException'],
 'es': ['BaseException', 'DisabledOperationException', 'InternalException', 'InvalidTypeException', 'LimitExceededException', 'ResourceAlreadyExistsException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ValidationException'],
 'events': ['ConcurrentModificationException', 'InternalException', 'InvalidEventPatternException', 'LimitExceededException', 'ManagedRuleException', 'PolicyLengthExceededException', 'ResourceNotFoundException'],
 'firehose': ['ConcurrentModificationException', 'InvalidArgumentException', 'LimitExceededException', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ServiceUnavailableException'],
 'glacier': ['InsufficientCapacityException', 'InvalidParameterValueException', 'LimitExceededException', 'MissingParameterValueException', 'PolicyEnforcedException', 'RequestTimeoutException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ServiceUnavailableException'],
 'glue': ['AccessDeniedException', 'AlreadyExistsException', 'ConcurrentModificationException', 'ConcurrentRunsExceededException', 'ConditionCheckFailureException', 'CrawlerNotRunningException', 'CrawlerRunningException', 'CrawlerStoppingException', 'EntityNotFoundException', 'GlueEncryptionException', 'IdempotentParameterMismatchException', 'InternalServiceException', 'InvalidInputException', 'NoScheduleException', 'OperationTimeoutException', 'ResourceNumberLimitExceededException', 'SchedulerNotRunningException', 'SchedulerRunningException', 'SchedulerTransitioningException', 'ValidationException', 'VersionMismatchException'],
 'iam': ['ConcurrentModification', 'ReportExpired', 'ReportNotPresent', 'ReportInProgress', 'DeleteConflict', 'DuplicateCertificate', 'DuplicateSSHPublicKey', 'EntityAlreadyExists', 'EntityTemporarilyUnmodifiable', 'InvalidAuthenticationCode', 'InvalidCertificate', 'InvalidInput', 'InvalidPublicKey', 'InvalidUserType', 'KeyPairMismatch', 'LimitExceeded', 'MalformedCertificate', 'MalformedPolicyDocument', 'NoSuchEntity', 'PasswordPolicyViolation', 'PolicyEvaluation', 'PolicyNotAttachable', 'ServiceFailure', 'NotSupportedService', 'UnmodifiableEntity', 'UnrecognizedPublicKeyEncoding'],
 'kinesis': ['ExpiredIteratorException', 'ExpiredNextTokenException', 'InternalFailureException', 'InvalidArgumentException', 'KMSAccessDeniedException', 'KMSDisabledException', 'KMSInvalidStateException', 'KMSNotFoundException', 'KMSOptInRequired', 'KMSThrottlingException', 'LimitExceededException', 'ProvisionedThroughputExceededException', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceNotFoundException'],
 'kms': ['AlreadyExistsException', 'CloudHsmClusterInUseException', 'CloudHsmClusterInvalidConfigurationException', 'CloudHsmClusterNotActiveException', 'CloudHsmClusterNotFoundException', 'CloudHsmClusterNotRelatedException', 'CustomKeyStoreHasCMKsException', 'CustomKeyStoreInvalidStateException', 'CustomKeyStoreNameInUseException', 'CustomKeyStoreNotFoundException', 'DependencyTimeoutException', 'DisabledException', 'ExpiredImportTokenException', 'IncorrectKeyMaterialException', 'IncorrectTrustAnchorException', 'InvalidAliasNameException', 'InvalidArnException', 'InvalidCiphertextException', 'InvalidGrantIdException', 'InvalidGrantTokenException', 'InvalidImportTokenException', 'InvalidKeyUsageException', 'InvalidMarkerException', 'KMSInternalException', 'KMSInvalidStateException', 'KeyUnavailableException', 'LimitExceededException', 'MalformedPolicyDocumentException', 'NotFoundException', 'TagException', 'UnsupportedOperationException'],
 'lambda': ['CodeStorageExceededException', 'EC2AccessDeniedException', 'EC2ThrottledException', 'EC2UnexpectedException', 'ENILimitReachedException', 'InvalidParameterValueException', 'InvalidRequestContentException', 'InvalidRuntimeException', 'InvalidSecurityGroupIDException', 'InvalidSubnetIDException', 'InvalidZipFileException', 'KMSAccessDeniedException', 'KMSDisabledException', 'KMSInvalidStateException', 'KMSNotFoundException', 'PolicyLengthExceededException', 'PreconditionFailedException', 'RequestTooLargeException', 'ResourceConflictException', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ServiceException', 'SubnetIPAddressLimitReachedException', 'TooManyRequestsException', 'UnsupportedMediaTypeException'],
 'logs': ['DataAlreadyAcceptedException', 'InvalidOperationException', 'InvalidParameterException', 'InvalidSequenceTokenException', 'LimitExceededException', 'MalformedQueryException', 'OperationAbortedException', 'ResourceAlreadyExistsException', 'ResourceNotFoundException', 'ServiceUnavailableException', 'UnrecognizedClientException'],
 'neptune': ['AuthorizationNotFound', 'CertificateNotFound', 'DBClusterAlreadyExistsFault', 'DBClusterNotFoundFault', 'DBClusterParameterGroupNotFound', 'DBClusterQuotaExceededFault', 'DBClusterRoleAlreadyExists', 'DBClusterRoleNotFound', 'DBClusterRoleQuotaExceeded', 'DBClusterSnapshotAlreadyExistsFault', 'DBClusterSnapshotNotFoundFault', 'DBInstanceAlreadyExists', 'DBInstanceNotFound', 'DBParameterGroupAlreadyExists', 'DBParameterGroupNotFound', 'DBParameterGroupQuotaExceeded', 'DBSecurityGroupNotFound', 'DBSnapshotAlreadyExists', 'DBSnapshotNotFound', 'DBSubnetGroupAlreadyExists', 'DBSubnetGroupDoesNotCoverEnoughAZs', 'DBSubnetGroupNotFoundFault', 'DBSubnetGroupQuotaExceeded', 'DBSubnetQuotaExceededFault', 'DBUpgradeDependencyFailure', 'DomainNotFoundFault', 'EventSubscriptionQuotaExceeded', 'InstanceQuotaExceeded', 'InsufficientDBClusterCapacityFault', 'InsufficientDBInstanceCapacity', 'InsufficientStorageClusterCapacity', 'InvalidDBClusterSnapshotStateFault', 'InvalidDBClusterStateFault', 'InvalidDBInstanceState', 'InvalidDBParameterGroupState', 'InvalidDBSecurityGroupState', 'InvalidDBSnapshotState', 'InvalidDBSubnetGroupStateFault', 'InvalidDBSubnetStateFault', 'InvalidEventSubscriptionState', 'InvalidRestoreFault', 'InvalidSubnet', 'InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault', 'KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault', 'OptionGroupNotFoundFault', 'ProvisionedIopsNotAvailableInAZFault', 'ResourceNotFoundFault', 'SNSInvalidTopic', 'SNSNoAuthorization', 'SNSTopicArnNotFound', 'SharedSnapshotQuotaExceeded', 'SnapshotQuotaExceeded', 'SourceNotFound', 'StorageQuotaExceeded', 'StorageTypeNotSupported', 'SubnetAlreadyInUse', 'SubscriptionAlreadyExist', 'SubscriptionCategoryNotFound', 'SubscriptionNotFound'],
 'rds': ['AuthorizationAlreadyExists', 'AuthorizationNotFound', 'AuthorizationQuotaExceeded', 'BackupPolicyNotFoundFault', 'CertificateNotFound', 'DBClusterAlreadyExistsFault', 'DBClusterBacktrackNotFoundFault', 'DBClusterEndpointAlreadyExistsFault', 'DBClusterEndpointNotFoundFault', 'DBClusterEndpointQuotaExceededFault', 'DBClusterNotFoundFault', 'DBClusterParameterGroupNotFound', 'DBClusterQuotaExceededFault', 'DBClusterRoleAlreadyExists', 'DBClusterRoleNotFound', 'DBClusterRoleQuotaExceeded', 'DBClusterSnapshotAlreadyExistsFault', 'DBClusterSnapshotNotFoundFault', 'DBInstanceAlreadyExists', 'DBInstanceAutomatedBackupNotFound', 'DBInstanceAutomatedBackupQuotaExceeded', 'DBInstanceNotFound', 'DBInstanceRoleAlreadyExists', 'DBInstanceRoleNotFound', 'DBInstanceRoleQuotaExceeded', 'DBLogFileNotFoundFault', 'DBParameterGroupAlreadyExists', 'DBParameterGroupNotFound', 'DBParameterGroupQuotaExceeded', 'DBSecurityGroupAlreadyExists', 'DBSecurityGroupNotFound', 'DBSecurityGroupNotSupported', 'QuotaExceeded.DBSecurityGroup', 'DBSnapshotAlreadyExists', 'DBSnapshotNotFound', 'DBSubnetGroupAlreadyExists', 'DBSubnetGroupDoesNotCoverEnoughAZs', 'DBSubnetGroupNotAllowedFault', 'DBSubnetGroupNotFoundFault', 'DBSubnetGroupQuotaExceeded', 'DBSubnetQuotaExceededFault', 'DBUpgradeDependencyFailure', 'DomainNotFoundFault', 'EventSubscriptionQuotaExceeded', 'GlobalClusterAlreadyExistsFault', 'GlobalClusterNotFoundFault', 'GlobalClusterQuotaExceededFault', 'InstanceQuotaExceeded', 'InsufficientDBClusterCapacityFault', 'InsufficientDBInstanceCapacity', 'InsufficientStorageClusterCapacity', 'InvalidDBClusterCapacityFault', 'InvalidDBClusterEndpointStateFault', 'InvalidDBClusterSnapshotStateFault', 'InvalidDBClusterStateFault', 'InvalidDBInstanceAutomatedBackupState', 'InvalidDBInstanceState', 'InvalidDBParameterGroupState', 'InvalidDBSecurityGroupState', 'InvalidDBSnapshotState', 'InvalidDBSubnetGroupFault', 'InvalidDBSubnetGroupStateFault', 'InvalidDBSubnetStateFault', 'InvalidEventSubscriptionState', 'InvalidGlobalClusterStateFault', 'InvalidOptionGroupStateFault', 'InvalidRestoreFault', 'InvalidS3BucketFault', 'InvalidSubnet', 'InvalidVPCNetworkStateFault', 'KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault', 'OptionGroupAlreadyExistsFault', 'OptionGroupNotFoundFault', 'OptionGroupQuotaExceededFault', 'PointInTimeRestoreNotEnabled', 'ProvisionedIopsNotAvailableInAZFault', 'ReservedDBInstanceAlreadyExists', 'ReservedDBInstanceNotFound', 'ReservedDBInstanceQuotaExceeded', 'ReservedDBInstancesOfferingNotFound', 'ResourceNotFoundFault', 'SNSInvalidTopic', 'SNSNoAuthorization', 'SNSTopicArnNotFound', 'SharedSnapshotQuotaExceeded', 'SnapshotQuotaExceeded', 'SourceNotFound', 'StorageQuotaExceeded', 'StorageTypeNotSupported', 'SubnetAlreadyInUse', 'SubscriptionAlreadyExist', 'SubscriptionCategoryNotFound', 'SubscriptionNotFound'],
 'route53': ['ConcurrentModification', 'ConflictingDomainExists', 'ConflictingTypes', 'DelegationSetAlreadyCreated', 'DelegationSetAlreadyReusable', 'DelegationSetInUse', 'DelegationSetNotAvailable', 'DelegationSetNotReusable', 'HealthCheckAlreadyExists', 'HealthCheckInUse', 'HealthCheckVersionMismatch', 'HostedZoneAlreadyExists', 'HostedZoneNotEmpty', 'HostedZoneNotFound', 'HostedZoneNotPrivate', 'IncompatibleVersion', 'InsufficientCloudWatchLogsResourcePolicy', 'InvalidArgument', 'InvalidChangeBatch', 'InvalidDomainName', 'InvalidInput', 'InvalidPaginationToken', 'InvalidTrafficPolicyDocument', 'InvalidVPCId', 'LastVPCAssociation', 'LimitsExceeded', 'NoSuchChange', 'NoSuchCloudWatchLogsLogGroup', 'NoSuchDelegationSet', 'NoSuchGeoLocation', 'NoSuchHealthCheck', 'NoSuchHostedZone', 'NoSuchQueryLoggingConfig', 'NoSuchTrafficPolicy', 'NoSuchTrafficPolicyInstance', 'NotAuthorizedException', 'PriorRequestNotComplete', 'PublicZoneVPCAssociation', 'QueryLoggingConfigAlreadyExists', 'ThrottlingException', 'TooManyHealthChecks', 'TooManyHostedZones', 'TooManyTrafficPolicies', 'TooManyTrafficPolicyInstances', 'TooManyTrafficPolicyVersionsForCurrentPolicy', 'TooManyVPCAssociationAuthorizations', 'TrafficPolicyAlreadyExists', 'TrafficPolicyInUse', 'TrafficPolicyInstanceAlreadyExists', 'VPCAssociationAuthorizationNotFound', 'VPCAssociationNotFound'],
 's3': ['BucketAlreadyExists', 'BucketAlreadyOwnedByYou', 'NoSuchBucket', 'NoSuchKey', 'NoSuchUpload', 'ObjectAlreadyInActiveTierError', 'ObjectNotInActiveTierError'],
 'sagemaker': ['ResourceInUse', 'ResourceLimitExceeded', 'ResourceNotFound'],
 'secretsmanager': ['DecryptionFailure', 'EncryptionFailure', 'InternalServiceError', 'InvalidNextTokenException', 'InvalidParameterException', 'InvalidRequestException', 'LimitExceededException', 'MalformedPolicyDocumentException', 'PreconditionNotMetException', 'ResourceExistsException', 'ResourceNotFoundException'],
 'ses': ['AccountSendingPausedException', 'AlreadyExists', 'CannotDelete', 'ConfigurationSetAlreadyExists', 'ConfigurationSetDoesNotExist', 'ConfigurationSetSendingPausedException', 'CustomVerificationEmailInvalidContent', 'CustomVerificationEmailTemplateAlreadyExists', 'CustomVerificationEmailTemplateDoesNotExist', 'EventDestinationAlreadyExists', 'EventDestinationDoesNotExist', 'FromEmailAddressNotVerified', 'InvalidCloudWatchDestination', 'InvalidConfigurationSet', 'InvalidFirehoseDestination', 'InvalidLambdaFunction', 'InvalidPolicy', 'InvalidRenderingParameter', 'InvalidS3Configuration', 'InvalidSNSDestination', 'InvalidSnsTopic', 'InvalidTemplate', 'InvalidTrackingOptions', 'LimitExceeded', 'MailFromDomainNotVerifiedException', 'MessageRejected', 'MissingRenderingAttribute', 'ProductionAccessNotGranted', 'RuleDoesNotExist', 'RuleSetDoesNotExist', 'TemplateDoesNotExist', 'TrackingOptionsAlreadyExistsException', 'TrackingOptionsDoesNotExistException'],
 'sns': ['AuthorizationError', 'EndpointDisabled', 'FilterPolicyLimitExceeded', 'InternalError', 'InvalidParameter', 'ParameterValueInvalid', 'InvalidSecurity', 'KMSAccessDenied', 'KMSDisabled', 'KMSInvalidState', 'KMSNotFound', 'KMSOptInRequired', 'KMSThrottling', 'NotFound', 'PlatformApplicationDisabled', 'SubscriptionLimitExceeded', 'Throttled', 'TopicLimitExceeded'],
 'sqs': ['AWS.SimpleQueueService.BatchEntryIdsNotDistinct', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.BatchRequestTooLong', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.EmptyBatchRequest', 'InvalidAttributeName', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.InvalidBatchEntryId', 'InvalidIdFormat', 'InvalidMessageContents', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.MessageNotInflight', 'OverLimit', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.PurgeQueueInProgress', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.QueueDeletedRecently', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue', 'QueueAlreadyExists', 'ReceiptHandleIsInvalid', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.TooManyEntriesInBatchRequest', 'AWS.SimpleQueueService.UnsupportedOperation'],
 'ssm': ['AlreadyExistsException', 'AssociatedInstances', 'AssociationAlreadyExists', 'AssociationDoesNotExist', 'AssociationExecutionDoesNotExist', 'AssociationLimitExceeded', 'AssociationVersionLimitExceeded', 'AutomationDefinitionNotFoundException', 'AutomationDefinitionVersionNotFoundException', 'AutomationExecutionLimitExceededException', 'AutomationExecutionNotFoundException', 'AutomationStepNotFoundException', 'ComplianceTypeCountLimitExceededException', 'CustomSchemaCountLimitExceededException', 'DocumentAlreadyExists', 'DocumentLimitExceeded', 'DocumentPermissionLimit', 'DocumentVersionLimitExceeded', 'DoesNotExistException', 'DuplicateDocumentContent', 'DuplicateDocumentVersionName', 'DuplicateInstanceId', 'FeatureNotAvailableException', 'HierarchyLevelLimitExceededException', 'HierarchyTypeMismatchException', 'IdempotentParameterMismatch', 'InternalServerError', 'InvalidActivation', 'InvalidActivationId', 'InvalidAggregatorException', 'InvalidAllowedPatternException', 'InvalidAssociation', 'InvalidAssociationVersion', 'InvalidAutomationExecutionParametersException', 'InvalidAutomationSignalException', 'InvalidAutomationStatusUpdateException', 'InvalidCommandId', 'InvalidDeleteInventoryParametersException', 'InvalidDeletionIdException', 'InvalidDocument', 'InvalidDocumentContent', 'InvalidDocumentOperation', 'InvalidDocumentSchemaVersion', 'InvalidDocumentVersion', 'InvalidFilter', 'InvalidFilterKey', 'InvalidFilterOption', 'InvalidFilterValue', 'InvalidInstanceId', 'InvalidInstanceInformationFilterValue', 'InvalidInventoryGroupException', 'InvalidInventoryItemContextException', 'InvalidInventoryRequestException', 'InvalidItemContentException', 'InvalidKeyId', 'InvalidNextToken', 'InvalidNotificationConfig', 'InvalidOptionException', 'InvalidOutputFolder', 'InvalidOutputLocation', 'InvalidParameters', 'InvalidPermissionType', 'InvalidPluginName', 'InvalidResourceId', 'InvalidResourceType', 'InvalidResultAttributeException', 'InvalidRole', 'InvalidSchedule', 'InvalidTarget', 'InvalidTypeNameException', 'InvalidUpdate', 'InvocationDoesNotExist', 'ItemContentMismatchException', 'ItemSizeLimitExceededException', 'MaxDocumentSizeExceeded', 'ParameterAlreadyExists', 'ParameterLimitExceeded', 'ParameterMaxVersionLimitExceeded', 'ParameterNotFound', 'ParameterPatternMismatchException', 'ParameterVersionLabelLimitExceeded', 'ParameterVersionNotFound', 'ResourceDataSyncAlreadyExistsException', 'ResourceDataSyncCountExceededException', 'ResourceDataSyncInvalidConfigurationException', 'ResourceDataSyncNotFoundException', 'ResourceInUseException', 'ResourceLimitExceededException', 'StatusUnchanged', 'SubTypeCountLimitExceededException', 'TargetInUseException', 'TargetNotConnected', 'TooManyTagsError', 'TooManyUpdates', 'TotalSizeLimitExceededException', 'UnsupportedInventoryItemContextException', 'UnsupportedInventorySchemaVersionException', 'UnsupportedOperatingSystem', 'UnsupportedParameterType', 'UnsupportedPlatformType'],
 'stepfunctions': ['ActivityDoesNotExist', 'ActivityLimitExceeded', 'ActivityWorkerLimitExceeded', 'ExecutionAlreadyExists', 'ExecutionDoesNotExist', 'ExecutionLimitExceeded', 'InvalidArn', 'InvalidDefinition', 'InvalidExecutionInput', 'InvalidName', 'InvalidOutput', 'InvalidToken', 'MissingRequiredParameter', 'ResourceNotFound', 'StateMachineAlreadyExists', 'StateMachineDeleting', 'StateMachineDoesNotExist', 'StateMachineLimitExceeded', 'TaskDoesNotExist', 'TaskTimedOut', 'TooManyTags'],
 'sts': ['ExpiredTokenException', 'IDPCommunicationError', 'IDPRejectedClaim', 'InvalidAuthorizationMessageException', 'InvalidIdentityToken', 'MalformedPolicyDocument', 'PackedPolicyTooLarge', 'RegionDisabledException'],
 'xray': ['InvalidRequestException', 'RuleLimitExceededException', 'ThrottledException']}
```

Comment: There is a mistake in the example code.

service: list(boto3.client('sts').exceptions._code_to_exception), here "sts" should be replaced with "service"

Answer (score 14):

- Only one import needed.
- No if statement needed.
- Use the client built-in exception as intended.

Ex:

```
from boto3 import client

cli = client('iam')
try:
    cli.create_user(
        UserName = 'Brian'
    )
except cli.exceptions.EntityAlreadyExistsException:
    pass
```

a CloudWatch example:

```
cli = client('logs')
try:
    cli.create_log_group(
        logGroupName = 'MyLogGroup'
    )
except cli.exceptions.ResourceAlreadyExistsException:
    pass
```

Answer (score 4):

Or a comparison on the class name e.g.

```
except ClientError as e:
    if 'EntityAlreadyExistsException' == e.__class__.__name__:
        # handle specific error
```

Because they are dynamically created you can never import the class and catch it using real Python.

Comment: So i would be catching all exceptions with `except Exception as e` and then have if statements to determine the specific exception? How's that different from/better than catching specific exceptions? Its more lines, and you would need to import the library to get the class name anyway. Unless you wanna go with hardcoding the exception name.

All in all, it seems like a bad way to go about it.

Comment: @SQDK sorry my answer was unclear, but not what you are talking about.  I have updated it.

Answer (score 3):

In case you have to deal with the arguably unfriendly `logs` client ([CloudWatch Logs `put-log-events`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.put_log_events)), this is what I had to do to properly catch Boto3 client exceptions:

```
try:
    ### Boto3 client code here...

except boto_exceptions.ClientError as error:
    Log.warning("Catched client error code %s",
                error.response['Error']['Code'])

    if error.response['Error']['Code'] in ["DataAlreadyAcceptedException",
                                           "InvalidSequenceTokenException"]:
        Log.debug(
            "Fetching sequence_token from boto error response['Error']['Message'] %s",
            error.response["Error"]["Message"])
        # NOTE: apparently there's no sequenceToken attribute in the response so we have
        # to parse response["Error"]["Message"] string
        sequence_token = error.response["Error"]["Message"].split(":")[-1].strip(" ")
        Log.debug("Setting sequence_token to %s", sequence_token)
```

This works both at first attempt (with empty LogStream) and subsequent ones.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the sign_up API (AWS Cognito) using Python3, you can use the following code.

```
def registerUser(userObj):
    ''' Registers the user to AWS Cognito.
    '''

    # Mobile number is not a mandatory field. 
    if(len(userObj['user_mob_no']) == 0):
        mobilenumber = ''
    else:
        mobilenumber = userObj['user_country_code']+userObj['user_mob_no']

    secretKey = bytes(settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_COGNITO_SECRET, 'latin-1')
    clientId = settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_COGNITO_KEY 

    digest = hmac.new(secretKey,
                msg=(userObj['user_name'] + clientId).encode('utf-8'),
                digestmod=hashlib.sha256
                ).digest()
    signature = base64.b64encode(digest).decode()

    client = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region_name='eu-west-1' ) 

    try:
        response = client.sign_up(
                    ClientId=clientId,
                    Username=userObj['user_name'],
                    Password=userObj['password1'],
                    SecretHash=signature,
                    UserAttributes=[
                        {
                            'Name': 'given_name',
                            'Value': userObj['given_name']
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'family_name',
                            'Value': userObj['family_name']
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'email',
                            'Value': userObj['user_email']
                        },
                        {
                            'Name': 'phone_number',
                            'Value': mobilenumber
                        }
                    ],
                    ValidationData=[
                        {
                            'Name': 'email',
                            'Value': userObj['user_email']
                        },
                    ]
                    ,
                    AnalyticsMetadata={
                        'AnalyticsEndpointId': 'string'
                    },
                    UserContextData={
                        'EncodedData': 'string'
                    }
                )
    except ClientError as error:
        return {"errorcode": error.response['Error']['Code'],
            "errormessage" : error.response['Error']['Message'] }
    except Exception as e:
        return {"errorcode": "Something went wrong. Try later or contact the admin" }
    return {"success": "User registered successfully. "}
```

error.response['Error']['Code'] will be InvalidPasswordException, UsernameExistsException etc. So in the main function or where you are calling the function, you can write the logic to provide a meaningful message to the user.

An example for the response (error.response):

```
{
  "Error": {
    "Message": "Password did not conform with policy: Password must have symbol characters",
    "Code": "InvalidPasswordException"
  },
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "c8a591d5-8c51-4af9-8fad-b38b270c3ca2",
    "HTTPStatusCode": 400,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "date": "Wed, 17 Jul 2019 09:38:32 GMT",
      "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "content-length": "124",
      "connection": "keep-alive",
      "x-amzn-requestid": "c8a591d5-8c51-4af9-8fad-b38b270c3ca2",
      "x-amzn-errortype": "InvalidPasswordException:",
      "x-amzn-errormessage": "Password did not conform with policy: Password must have symbol characters"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  }
}
```

For further reference :
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cognito-idp.html#CognitoIdentityProvider.Client.sign_up

Answer (score 1):

Following @armod's update about exceptions being added right on `client` objects. I'll show how you can see all exceptions defined for your client class.

Exceptions are generated dynamically when you create your client with `session.create_client()` or `boto3.client()`. Internally it calls method [`botocore.errorfactory.ClientExceptionsFactory._create_client_exceptions()`](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/errorfactory.py#L76) and fills `client.exceptions` field with constructed exception classes.

All class names are available in `client.exceptions._code_to_exception` dictionary, so you can list all types with following snippet:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')

for ex_code in client.exceptions._code_to_exception:
    print(ex_code)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -5):

You need to do something when it fails to handle the issue.  Right now you are returning the actual exception. 
For example, if its not a problem that the user exists already and you want to use it as a get_or_create function maybe you handle the issue by returning the existing user object.

```
try:
    user = iam_conn.create_user(UserName=username)
    return user
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:

    #this exception could actually be other things other than exists, so you want to evaluate it further in your real code.
    if e.message.startswith(
        'enough of the exception message to identify it as the one you want')

        print('that user already exists.')
        user = iam_conn.get_user(UserName=username)
        return user

    elif e.message.some_other_condition:

         #something else
    else:
         #unhandled ClientError
         raise(e)
except SomeOtherExceptionTypeYouCareAbout as e:
    #handle it

# any unhandled exception will raise here at this point.
# if you want a general handler

except Exception as e:
    #handle it.
```

That said, maybe it is a problem for your app, in which case you want to want to put the exception handler around the code that called your create user function and let the calling function determine how to deal with it, for example, by asking the user to input another username, or whatever makes sense for your application.

Comment: But that the user already exists is only one of more ways that the API call can fail. I don't see a way to differentiate between these with this method.

Comment: Just demoing how exception handling works at a base level because that seems to be where the confusion is.  I put a comment to that effect.

Comment: Thanks for that. That only enforces my suspicion that this question is more boto3-specific that python-specific. I am not aware of common patterns for error handling in python, hence my generic way of asking the question

Comment: Exception objects have properties that you can evalulate further to break up the handling.  Ones that get used commonly for this are "message" and "args"

Comment: I have got the source for the ClientError exception right here: https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/exceptions.py#L292. Doesn't that look like it just gets formatted in a string? May be a "problem" with the way boto3 handles that kind of errors. Maybe the devs are assuming that there is only 2 possible scenarios (that the user already exists or doesn't) which justifies just throwing an exception with only a string if it didn't work.

Comment: I added some general examples of how to further parse the exception

Comment: I didn't think of that. The only thing i don't like is that a change in the error message will break my code and a http status code wouldn't. I'll accept this as the answer if no better solution shows up.

Comment: Based on the source you linked, if you really need to handle every possible situation, it looks like you could parse the AWS error code out of the message with string functions and then feed the error code to a lookup table of all the possible aws error codes.

Comment: Don't test the message contents. Instead test e.response['Error']['Code']. For example it will contain 'ValidationError'. I recommend printing out dir(e) to find out what's available to you in the exception object (because the boto3 docs are sorely lacking in any help on errors/exceptions).

Comment: And more specifically: if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'EntityAlreadyExists'