# How can I import the boto3 ssm ParameterNotFound exception?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, botocore, moto

I would like to `import` the `exception` that occurs when a `boto3` `ssm` parameter is not found with `get_parameter`.  I'm trying to add some extra `ssm` functionality to the `moto` library, but I am stumped at this point.

```
>>> import boto3
>>> ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
>>> try:
        ssm.get_parameter(Name='not_found')
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e))
<class 'botocore.errorfactory.ParameterNotFound'>
>>> from botocore.errorfactory import ParameterNotFound
ImportError: cannot import name 'ParameterNotFound'
>>> import botocore.errorfactory.ParameterNotFound
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'botocore.errorfactory.ParameterNotFound'; 'botocore.errorfactory' is not a package
```

However, the `Exception` cannot be imported, and does not appear to exist in the botocore code.  How can I import this exception?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From [Botocore Error Handling](http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client_upgrades.html#error-handling)

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
try:
    ssm.get_parameter(Name='not_found')
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Code'])
```

Comment: This isn't difficult to understand from a code perspective. What's difficult to understand from a design perspective is that you can't directly import or name an error from its callstack name in boto3. Neither `import botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException` or `except botocore.errorfactory.ResourceNotFoundException` work. But both are what one would immediately want to try after receiving said error. Puzzling.

Comment: Also see this answer for more info about the structure of the ClientError response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33663484

Answer (score 35):

```
mc = boto3.client('ssm')
try:
  ...
except mc.exceptions.ParameterNotFound:
  ...
```

Comment: When I try this and it reaches the `except` line it generates an exception stating `exceptions must derive from the base class` so I question if this is really valid