# Boto3 InvalidParameterException while executing the lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, boto, botocore

I'm getting a Boto3 InvalidParameterException while running the lambda function.
I'm trying to find out a way to handle this exception.

I came across the below solution:

```
from boto.exception import BotoServerError

class InvalidParameterException(BotoServerError):
    pass
```

I'm using python3 and understood that boto is deprecated now and is replaced by boto3.
But i could not find an equivalent solution in boto3.

Can anyone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `boto` is deprecated all the `modeled` exceptions are available on the client. You can look it up same in the API docs as well , basically the code for the `boto3` is straight away generated from the APIs. Earlier approach with `boto` was hard coded stuff and writing code for the same.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/master/botocore/data)

For example

```py
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def get_secret():
    secret_name = "MySecretName"
    region_name = "us-west-2"

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name,
    )

    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            print("The requested secret " + secret_name + " was not found")
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            print("The request was invalid due to:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            print("The request had invalid params:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailure':
            print("The requested secret can't be decrypted using the provided KMS key:", e)
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceError':
            print("An error occurred on service side:", e)
```

[AWS Secrets Manager Example From the docss](https://github.com/boto/boto3/blob/72a83a3ef08ac20d3848d4342a63d715c3e57cd3/docs/source/guide/secrets-manager.rst#example)

[How to handle errors with boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068055/how-to-handle-errors-with-boto3/33663484#33663484)

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. The botocore library generates several exceptions from a base class. So, it's better to Catch the baseclass and then handle the exception as we need