# How to know whether there is a exception that untreated in scala code?

Tags: scala

in java, if there is a exception in code and you are untreated or not throwing out, compiling will be failed. But in scala, it will be compiling successfully.

So how to know whether there is a exception that untreated in scala code?

Comment: The [prevalent opinion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/613954/2032064) on checked exceptions is that they are not a good idea so you shouldn't miss them much.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is the same as for unchecked exceptions (RuntimeExceptions) in Java: the compiler won't complain about them not being handled.

You have to rely on the source code and documentation to see what exceptions you might get from a piece of code.

In Scala, you should probably avoid exceptions in favour of `Try` monads when you expect the caller to deal with them (i.e. when you would use a checked exception in Java).

Comment: But I don't konw whether there is a exception, how to avoid it? how do you check exception in scala?

Comment: You cannot. All exceptions are unchecked. Of course, you can still catch them if you feel that you should. But the compiler won't force you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Guo  You should consider to award this answer as correct.