# Clarification on throws declaration

Tags: java, try-catch, sqlexception, throws

I have the following SQL transaction in java

```
public List<MyObj> find() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<MyObj> obj = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String sql = " some sql query";
            SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.addEntity(MyObj.class);
            objs = query.list();
            tx.commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();

        }
        finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return objs;

    }
```

Should I be catching an SQLException instead of Exception? When I change the class to be SQL Exception I get an error that I should be adding a throws clause and then removing the catch clause.

Can I add a throws declaration and still catch and handle the SQLException? in this case rollback?

Comment: What is the exact error from compiler?

Comment: Unreachable catch block for SQLException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Comment: Hibernate wraps exceptions in a HibernateException, so you can just catch that. RuntimeException will work too but then you are catching more than just a HibernateException. Better to be specific.

Comment: `catch(Exception ...)` is an antipattern, as is `throws Exception`. Always deal in more specific exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate API does not throw the `SQLException` (which is a checked `Exception`), so you can't catch it.

The good practice is to `catch` `RuntimeException` (to handle exceptions occurred because of code issues like null references, etc... or exceptions thrown by Hibernate API) and `rollback` the transaction, you can look Hibernate docs [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html) for examples on transaction rollback.

```
try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String sql = " some sql query";
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        query.addEntity(MyObj.class);
        objs = query.list();
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e) {
        if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
         throw e;
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

> I think what the error means is that I should first declare a throws
>   clause indicating that the block of code will throw an SQLEXception
>   correct?

No, because Hibernate already wraps the checked `SQLException` into one of the unchecked Exception objects (list given below), you don't need to either `catch` that Exception or need `throws` clause on method signature.

I strongly suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613954/the-case-against-checked-exceptions) link on why Hibernate or Spring frameworks have moved out of checked exceptions (like `SQLException`, etc..).

> Is there a doc that says that SQLexception is not thrown by the
>   hibernate API?

You can look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/exception/package-summary.html) for the list of Hibernate exceptions.

Comment: I think what the error means is that  I should first declare a throws clause indicating that the block of code will throw an SQLEXception correct? Is there a doc that says that SQLexception is not thrown by the hibernate API ?

Comment: Updated the answer, have a look

Comment: @user_mda "Is there a doc that says that SQLexception is not thrown by the hibernate [sic] API ?" Yes, the Hibernate Javadocs. Have you looked into them?