# How do I refactor closing a stream in Java?

Tags: java, refactoring, error-handling, stream

Due to my company's policy of using Eclipse and using Eclipse's code-autofix, the following code pattern appears excessively in the codebase:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    // .....
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
} finally {
    if (is != null) {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle error
       }
    }
}
```

IMO it's extremely fugly and hard to read, especially the portion within the finally block (is there really a need to catch 2 instances of IOException?). Is there anyway to streamline the code such that it looks cleaner?

Comment: Note that I cant use external libraries such as Apache IOUtils not unless it goes testing and approval by multiple entities

Comment: The whole point of using Apache IOUtils is that it has already been tested by countless other people.  That being said, I feel your pain.  Wouldn't it be worth it to have IOUtils tested and approved *once* within your organization so you can use it across all your projects?

Comment: If only life were that simple... I have to go through many levels of management and red tape to even get it seen by the working groups involved. And we're still stuck using JDK1.4.2 due to 'legacy' issues with software that has been retired ages ago

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: +1, fight the good fight.

Comment: @david: Print out a copy of this for your bosses and put it in their inbox: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html

Comment: I shudder to think what working in this environment might be like; one where the software developers are not trusted to make decisions about how to develop software

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588546/does-close-ever-throw-an-ioexception

Comment: Just throw the exception, it doesn't look like you can do anything meaningful with it anyway.

Comment: Just wondering isn't that `is` a reserved keyword?

Comment: okay, thanks. It is a reserved keyword in c# tho :)

Answer (score 3):

Why do *anything?* It's working code. It's correct.

Leave it be.

Comment: For the counter argument, http://www.klocwork.com/blog/2010/10/refactoring-if-it-aint-broken-dont-fix-it/

Comment: He didn't ask, "What should I do", he asked, "How do I do this."

Comment: And I am asking why. Why should there be a budget for disturbing working code? Working *generated* code at that. I regard generated code as object code personally, I don't mess with it.

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335812/try-catch-finally-and-then-again-a-try-catch), use the `closeQuietly()` solution.

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    // .....
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
} finally {
    IoUtils.closeQuietly(is);
}

// stolen from the cited question above
public class IoUtils {

  public static closeQuietly (Closeable closeable) {
    try {
      closeable.close();
    } catch (IOException logAndContinue) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Or wait for [JDK7's ARM blocks](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_updated_arm_spec).

Answer (score 1):

First, about using `IOUtils` - may worth a shot telling your supervisors that the very application-server / Java runtime environment they might use, uses `IOUtils` and similar libraries itself. so in essence you're not introducing new components to your architecture.

Second, no, not really. There isn't really any way around it other than writing your own utility that will immitate IOUtils' `closeQuietly` method.

Comment: Heh, if closeQuietly is opensource, copy it into your project.

Comment: ... And the inventor of reusability and modularity rests happily in his grave....

Comment: closeQuietly ignores the exception. That's never a good practice. Besides, david wants to "handle error".

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Util {
    public static void closeStream(inputStream is) {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
               is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // log something
        }
    }
}
```

Now your code is

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    // .....
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle error
} finally {
    Util.closeStream(is);
}
```

Not a lot else to do as the IOException in the catch might have some specific processing.

Comment: I like this, but I'd be inclined to go one step further, and create Util.openStream(url) so that callers aren't operating at 2 different levels of abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

You could define something like this somewhere:

```
private static interface InputStreamCallback {

    public void doIt(InputStream is) throws IOException;

}

private void with(InputStreamCallback cb) {

    InputStream is = null;

    // Creational code. Possibly adding an argument

    try {
        cb.doIt(is);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle error or rethrow.
        // If rethrow add throws to method spec.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // handle error or rethrow.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And invoke your code like this:

```
with(new InputStreamCallback() {

    @Override
    public void doIt(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        // .....
    }

});
```

If you declare with method `static` in a helper class, then you could even do an `import static` of it.

There's a drawback. You need to declare `url` final.

EDIT: creational code is not the point. You can arrange it in several ways. The callback is the point. You could isolate what you need to do there.