# IOException while closing BufferedInputStream

Tags: android

Following is the exception that I get: `java.io.IOException: I/O error`

```
04-13 07:11:35.040 W/System.err(  986):     at libcore.io.IoUtils.close(Native Method)
04-13 07:11:35.040 W/System.err(  986):     at java.io.FileInputStream.close (FileInputStream.java:139)
04-13 07:11:35.040 W/System.err(  986):     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close (BufferedInputStream.java:134)
```

Following is my code snippet:

```
public static void compress(String inFileName, String outFileName) { 
    GZIPOutputStream out = null;
    BufferedInputStream bin = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null; 
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    File inFile = null;
    try {
        inFile = new File(inFileName);
        if(inFile.exists()) 
        {

                fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
                out = new GZIPOutputStream(fileOutputStream);


                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
                bin = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);




            if(inFile.exists())
            {
                inFile.delete();
            }


            // Reading from buffer and writing it to file
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            FileOutputStream inFileOutputStream = null;
            int len;
            try
            {
                while((len = bin.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }

              //Close the inputstream since it is not required any more.

                fileInputStream.close();
                fileInputStream = null;

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {


            }
            finally
            {

            }

            out.finish();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    catch(MotoDCException e)
    {
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage(),e);
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {


            if(bin != null)
            {
                bin.close();
                bin = null;
            }

            if(fileOutputStream != null)
            {
                fileOutputStream.close();
                fileOutputStream = null;
            }
            if(out != null)
            {                   
                out.close();
                out = null;
            }
            inFile = null;
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {

            throw new MyException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

I get the exception only on an Android 3.0 device, when I try to close `bufferedInputStream` in the last finally block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because you are deleting the file at inFileName before closing the FileInputStream that you've opened from it. If you move your delete after the close, then it should work.

Comment: But i get an exception when i say bin.close() in the finally block.

Comment: And also , i get this exception only on Android 3.0

Comment: But you are closing the BufferedInputStream object after you have deleted the file, and after you have closed the FileInputStream that you have based your BuferedInputStream on.